# mongo db check if element of array is in string (OR Logic)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

hi i want to look if any of these names are in the database.
It should return the element when Julia OR Robert OR Max are saved in name. I am new in using MongoDB.
How can i do it?

**Database:**

```
[{name: "Julia"}, 
 {name:"someoneelse"}, 
 {name:"Max"}}]
```

**Result should be:**

```
[{name: "Julia"}, 
  {name:"Max"}}]
```

This does not work.

```
var names = ["Julia","Robert","Max"]
db.collections("names").find({
    name: names
}).toArray(function(err,result){
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: Use `find({     name: {$in:names} })`

Comment: thx this works fine